# Invalid plugin options for "gatsby-source-contentful"

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, access-token, contentful, gatsby-plugin

I'm encountering the following error when attempting to open a project I forked via GitHub.

```
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.492s

 ERROR #11331  PLUGIN

Invalid plugin options for "gatsby-source-contentful":

- "accessToken" is required

not finished load plugins - 6.220s
```

I've made several edits but am unable to work on the project as I'm unable to open it at the moment.  I do have a contentful account, but am fairly new to Gatsby and am unaware of how to set a new value for the `accessToken`.

**Would I need to do this via `process.env`, or am I missing the process entirely?**

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Would I need to do this via `process.env`, or am I missing the process
> entirely?

Absolutely, you need to provide to Gatsby and Contentful your access tokens. Gatsby, by default, takes the `.env.development` and `.env.production` when running `gatsby develop` and `gatsby build` respectively, so you will need to add the credentials to the [environment files](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/).

First of all, add the following snippet in your `gatsby-node.js`, above the module exportation:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

This will tell Gatsby which file needs to be taken in each running command.

The next step is to fill the environment files, in both of them add:

```
CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN=123456
CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID=78910
```

So, finally your `gatsby-config.js` should look like:

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may `not` be having `.env` file at application root.